# Hitting a Button -> Executing any class function I give it in the parameters (C++)

Tags: c++, callback

Can anyone help me with class function parameter callbacks? 
I'm not so sure how to set it up in my code here: 
http://codepad.org/fvwHtDjQ
Basically I've got a player and an enemy. 
I have two buttons. 
One button when clicked should let the player jump. The other should make the enemy hit something.

When clicked, each button has to correspond to the class function in the parameters.
I'm not sure how to set it up though.

Comment: Your other question had a very acceptable answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275742/callbacks-from-a-class-method-c . Did you not understand the answer? Then please ask in the comments. After reading your code, your problem seems to be a different one but you didn't phrase it any different. You are asking how to generate/handle the button events and not how to add callbacks.

Comment: You should include your code in the question, not an external link.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently trying to query whether the mouse is pushed and/or on a button. What you should do is use the event-handling mechanism of whatever GUI framework you use. If you don't want to do that, you can always poll for inputs in your game-loop, which you are either missing or omitted from your code.

Also, you implemented the suggested functor solution wrong unless you have some pretty weird macros.

```
//Button.cpp
template <typename class_t>
void Button::selected(class_t& c, void (class_t::* mp)()) {
  (c.*mp)();
}
```

But in your program you should probably save the class and method in `Button` and just call it in `selected()`

```
//Button.h
template <typename class_t>
class Button{
    private:
        class_t *target_obj;
        void (class_t::* func)();
    public:
        Button();
        void setFunc(class_t& c, void (class_t::* mp)());
        void selected();
};

//Button.cpp
template <typename class_t> Button<class_t>::Button() : target_obj(0) , func(0)
{
}

template <typename class_t> void Button<class_t>::setFunc(class_t& c, void (class_t::* mp)())
{
    target_obj = &c;
    func = mp;
}
template <typename class_t> void Button<class_t>::selected()
{
    if(target_obj!=0 && func !=0)
    {
        target_obj->func();
    }
}
```

You should still prefer the event-driven solution that I described in the first paragraph